# Can't figure out how to make container's edges completely rounded?

Tags: css

I'm trying to round the corners of the video container on this page: http://tstand.com/homepage-test/

For some reason there are white pointy edges on the bottom left and right. I've inspected source a bunch of times and can't see where this white background is coming from.

If someone could tell me which class I should be adding the border-radius to that would be great. Also, this is a minor detail, but I feel like the edges aren't that smooth, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates your problem, rather than expecting us to go digging through your code looking for it.

Comment: Looks like the usual sub-pixel issue.

Comment: Looks fine in macOS Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/vFEwKD8.png

Comment: try adding the `border-radius` rule to the image itself rather than to its container.

Comment: @Shaggy sorry, I figured someone with more experience would easily be able to diagnose the problem by inspecting source

Comment: @KevinJantzer strange that it looks fine for you because I'm also using Chrome on a Mac!

Comment: @AngelaMartinez - what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the following code should help in your case:

```
.page-id-965 .et_pb_video_box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It seems that the video element goes outside the container - that's why the overflow hidden helps as applying border-radius to the video element not work.

Comment: on my view of the OP website the video placeholder appears fine but the images underneath it have an ugly misfit sizing and overlap.

Comment: Thank you Tomasz, that worked like a charm. I would love to vote up your answer but my reputation is too low.

Comment: You can always upvote and accept answers to your questions ...It's **your** question, after all